# issue app_url: undefined in vite config in laravel project

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, vite

I'm trying to use vite in my laravel project. but after i run npm run dev in terminal, app_url is still undefined. how can i replace my resources paths and fix this issue.

this is my vite.config.js file

```
import {defineConfig} from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import path from 'path'


// Load environment variables
const APP_URL = process.env.APP_URL || 'http://mart.test';

export default defineConfig({
    server: {
        host: 'mart.test',
        hmr: {
            host: 'mart.test',
        },
    },
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                './src/resources/sass/app.scss',
                './src/resources/js/app.js',
            ],
            refresh: [{
                paths: ["packages/mart/theme/**"],
                config: {delay: 300}
            }],
            publicDirectory: "../../../public/hot",
            env: {
                APP_URL: APP_URL,
            },
        }),
    ],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '~bootstrap': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/bootstrap'),
        }
    },
});
```

and this is my app-url in .env file

```
APP_URL=http://mart.test
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
process.env.APP_URL
```

try this

```
import.meta.env.APP_URL
```